# Error while creating the menu in python using tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter

As you can see , whenever I'm going to run the code,
there is an error shows like this(`_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-Label"`)
what is the problem with the Label function?

```py
from tkinter import *
    
def donothing():
    print("It's just an example")
    
window = Tk()
    
menu = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=menu)
    
submenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(Label="File", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(Label="New File", command=donothing)
submenu.add_command(Label="Save", command=donothing)
submenu.add_command(Label="Save As", command=donothing)
submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(Label="Exit", command=donothing)
    
submenu2 = Menu(menu)
submenu2.add_cascade(Label="Edit", menu=submenu2)
submenu2.add_command(Label="Undo", command=donothing)
    
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try changing `Label` to `label`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for this

```
from tkinter import *
    
def donothing():
    print("It's just an example")
    
window = Tk()
    
menu = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=menu)
    
submenu = Menu(menu,tearoff=False)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label="New File", command=donothing)
submenu.add_command(label="Save", command=donothing)
submenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=donothing)
submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=donothing)
    
submenu2 = Menu(menu)
submenu2.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=submenu2)
submenu2.add_command(label="Undo", command=donothing)
    
window.mainloop()
```